# How can I get a list of long running processes that match a particular pattern?

Tags: linux, centos, ps

I know that I can do `ps aux | grep cgi` to get a list of all cgi scripts currently running, and `ps -p [pid] -o etime=` can get me the run time for each pid; is there a way to combine the two, or better still, only return those that have been running for "too long" (say, 45sec)?

Ideally, I'm looking for something that could be put into a perl script that looks out for issues, emails me the details and pro-actively kills the process "for safety". would it be better to just strap a the output from one, and then iterate through the results?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've done something like this in the past.

```
ps -A -o etime,pid,user,args| grep init
```

returns

```
180-04:55:20    1 root     init [5]
```

Which is easily parse-able in perl.
I used split and pop to parse it.

The format is [[dd-]hh:]mm:ss

Comment: Honestly, I would use http://search.cpan.org/~durist/Proc-ProcessTable-0.45/ProcessTable.pm . The above scenario was done in a unix environment where installing perl modules was 'expensive'

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this you might run [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), which as designed for this already.